# Can not get PN532 and mcp2515 to work together on arduino

Tags: arduino, nfc, can-bus

I am trying to make the PN532 NFC reader module and mcp2515 to work together.
This is my code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <mcp2515.h> //Library for using CAN Communication
#include <PN532_SPI.h>
#include <PN532.h>
#include <NfcAdapter.h>

#define deviceAddress 0x42

struct can_frame canMsg;
MCP2515 mcp2515(10);

PN532_SPI pn532spi1(SPI, 5);
PN532_SPI pn532spi2(SPI, 6);
NfcAdapter nfc1 = NfcAdapter(pn532spi1);
NfcAdapter nfc2 = NfcAdapter(pn532spi2);

void setup(void) {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Starting...");

    mcp2515.reset();
    mcp2515.setBitrate(CAN_10KBPS, MCP_8MHZ);
    mcp2515.setNormalMode();
    delay(100);
    nfc1.begin();
    delay(100);
    nfc2.begin();
}
 
void sendMessage(int data) {
  canMsg.can_id = deviceAddress;
  canMsg.can_dlc = 1;
  canMsg.data[0] = data;
  mcp2515.sendMessage(&canMsg);
}

void loop() {
    if (nfc1.tagPresent())
    {
      Serial.println("Kattenhoofd");
        NfcTag tag1 = nfc1.read();
        if (tag1.getUidString() == "6C 1A D6 B9") {
          Serial.println("YASSS!!!");
        }
    }

   if (nfc2.tagPresent())
    {
      Serial.println("Konijnenvoet");
        NfcTag tag2 = nfc2.read();
        if (tag2.getUidString() == "59 07 CA 5C") {
          Serial.println("YASSS!!!");
        }
    }

    if (mcp2515.readMessage(&canMsg) == MCP2515::ERROR_OK) {
      Serial.println("RECEIVED");
    }
}
```

When I try this the two NFC readers only read the value once and then stop reading the tag.
Is there something wrong with my code? All the wiring is done correctly.
When I remove the mcp2515 and it initializations the nfc readers work as expected.

Comment: Any time you can't get two microcontroller peripherals to "work together," you should immediately suspect that there are some pin overlaps, or competing needs for a particular timer, stuff like that.  Especially if disconnecting one restores correct operation to the other.